# wxPython: scrollbars interfering with formatting

Tags: wxpython, scrollbar, scrolledwindow

The following code is intended to demonstrate a problem I'm having with wxPython.
When I substitute a `wx.Panel` with a `wx.ScrolledWindow` and then run the program
the window that is opened is about as small as it could possibly be. Once the frame has been
manually resized the program works okay, but obviously I'd prefer the window to open
with a sensible size - as it does it I use a subclass of `panel` instead of a `scrolledwindow`. I've
tried all the obvious stuff like `SetBestSize`, `SetInitialSize` but to no avail.

```
import wx


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Example(None, title="Top frame")
        self.frame.SetInitialSize()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True


class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, ): 
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,size=(300, 350))

        self.panelOne = MyPanel(self)

        self.frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.frameSizer.Add(self.panelOne, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.frameSizer)
        self.frameSizer.Fit(self)

        self.Centre() 
        self.Show()


class MyPanel(wx.ScrolledWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)


        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.SetScrollbars(1,1,400,200)
        self.entryGrid = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols = 8, rows = 10)

        for i in range(80):
            x = wx.StaticText(self, id=-1, label=str(i), size=(-1,-1), pos=(-1,-1), style=0, name="")
            self.entryGrid.Add(x, 1, wx.ALL, 20)
        ### widgets here


        self.mainSizer.Add(self.entryGrid)
        # set optimum layout for mainsizer...
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        # ...then fit main sizer to the panel.
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following code and see if it does what you want:

HTH.

Andrea.

```
import wx


class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):

        self.frame = Example(None, title="Top frame")
        self.frame.SetInitialSize()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True


class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, size=(300, 350)): 

        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title)

        self.panelOne = MyPanel(self, size)

        self.frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.frameSizer.Add(self.panelOne, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.frameSizer)
        self.frameSizer.Layout()

        self.Centre() 
        self.Show()


class MyPanel(wx.ScrolledWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent, size):

        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 400, 200)

        self.entryGrid = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=8, rows=10)

        for i in range(80):
            x = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(i))
            self.entryGrid.Add(x, 1, wx.ALL, 20)

        self.mainSizer.Add(self.entryGrid)
        # set optimum layout for mainsizer...
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

        self.SetSizeHints(*size)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```